# How to add the background-color for data in table using bootstrap-classes and angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to do a small E-commerce application. After done the order by the user, admin got orders and order item  consist of `order id`, `itemname`, `price`, `status`, `btnclass`.

Default status of the order is pending and value of  btnclass is label-warning, After editing  the order pending to delivered the value of the btnclass change to the label-success. but i don't know how to do this

`btnclass` is for storing the bootstrap class.

```
<table>
    <th>order id</th>
    <th>item name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>status</th>
    <th>total</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in orders">
        <td>{{item.orderid}}</td>
        <td>{{item.itemname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price}}</td>
        <td><p class="label {{list.btnclass}}">{{item.status}}</p></td>
        <td>{{item.total}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My array is like this:

```
[
    {
        "orderid":1,
        "itemname":"rice",
        "price":10,
        "status":"pending",
        "btnclass":"label-warning",
        "total":10
    },
    {
        "orderid":2,
        "itemname":oils,
        "price":50,
        "status":"deliverd",
        "btnclass":"label-success",
        "total":50
    }
```

Please help me how to provide classes for the table data..

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very easy, you have to use ng-class.

With ng-class you can pass a group of classes and conditions that determine if the classes should be applied or not, the syntaxis is this

```
<any  ng-class="{'my-class':condition===true, 'my-second-class': someFunction()}"   />
```

notice that the parameter passed to ng-class is a js object, where the keys are the name of the classes to apply, and the values are the conditions, if a condition resolves to true then the class used as key will be applied, otherwise it will be ignored. As you can see you can either use expressions like in the first case *(condition===true)* or you can call functions like I did in the second example *(someFunction())* try to use this to solve your problem, and, if you can't feel free to ask for further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-class` is useful for that. You can create 2 CSS classes for the status, for example `.delivered` or `.pending`. And use ng-class directive as such :

```
<td><p ng-class="{'deliverd' : item.status === 'delivered', 'pending' === 'item.status === 'pending'}">{{item.status}}</p></td>
```

Comment: Thank you. it is very simple.